# Finding of linear transformation $S$ such that $TS=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Possibly duplicate

$T$ is a linear transformation from $R³$ to $R²$ given by $T(x,y,z)=(x+2y,x-z)$
Consider $w={v \in R³/v.u=0 , \forall u\in N(T)}$ (. Represents dot product)

Find a linear transformation $S$ from $R²$ to $w$ such that $TS= I $ where $I$ is Identity transformation on $R²$

My approach :- I found out $N(T) ={ k(-2,1,-2)/k \in R}$
Then, $w= { (x,y,z)/ -2x+y-2z=0}$
From here I am not getting how to find $S$ such that the given condition satisfies.

Any hints is really appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linear map $S$ is determined by the images of a basis. So just calculate the image of $e_1=\pmatrix{1\\0}$ and $e_2=\pmatrix{0\\1}$.

By hypothesis, we need $S(e_i)\in W$, thus according to your calculation, $S(e_i)=\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}$ where $z=\frac{y-2x}2$.

Additionally, we want $S$ to satisfy $TS=I$, therefore $TS(e_i)=e_i$ for both  $i=1,2$.

All in all, you have to solve
$$T\pmatrix{x\\y\\ \frac{y-2x}2} \ =\ \pmatrix{1 \\0}\ \text{ and}\\
T\pmatrix{x\\y\\ \frac{y-2x}2} \ =\ \pmatrix{0\\1}$$

Comment: I didn't got , can you please specify it more clearly .

Comment: I elaborated on it.

Comment: Thank you very much